# specific IDs do not accept my access token in RestFB for Facebook

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, groovy, access-token, restfb

I try to fetch multiple objects through the RestFB API. I have a list of IDs (endpoints?) and want them to be bulk-fetched by RestFB. Therefore I use `FacebookClient.fetchObjects()`. The problem which now occurs is that one of the IDs in my list seems not to accept the token. I'm not that into the token system of facebook. The only token I generated is the **app-token**.

**Two IDs used in the list:**

> working ID: 1104054513000418
>   not working ID: 1106761186063084

These IDs belong to posts which are from the same author and there is not real difference between them but the content.

Trying to fetch data by these IDs manually (no bulk-fetch) I have the same issue. So it is not an issue with the misusage of the multiple fetch method.

**Code:**

```
FacebookClient.AccessToken accessToken = new DefaultFacebookClient().obtainAppAccessToken(appId, appSecurity);
FacebookClient fbClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(accessToken.getAccessToken());

// consider filteredSocialItems as given
List<String> filteredItemIDs = filteredSocialItems.stream()
        .map({ item -> item.properties.get("sourceId") })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

JsonObject json = fbClient.fetchObjects(filteredItemIDs, JsonObject.class, Parameter.with("fields", "name,id"));
```

**Exception:**

```
Caught: com.restfb.exception.FacebookOAuthException: Received Facebook error response of type OAuthException: (#100) Requires user session (code 100, subcode null)
com.restfb.exception.FacebookOAuthException: Received Facebook error response of type OAuthException: (#100) Requires user session (code 100, subcode null)
    at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient$DefaultGraphFacebookExceptionMapper.exceptionForTypeAndMessage(DefaultFacebookClient.java:1201)
    at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.throwFacebookResponseStatusExceptionIfNecessary(DefaultFacebookClient.java:1122)
    at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.makeRequestAndProcessResponse(DefaultFacebookClient.java:1063)
    at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.makeRequest(DefaultFacebookClient.java:974)
    at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.makeRequest(DefaultFacebookClient.java:936)
    at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.fetchObjects(DefaultFacebookClient.java:431)
    at facebookImageRefresh.run(facebookImageRefresh.groovy:48)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:48)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solving the problem was a bit exhausting. It was an issue with an old facebook app version.

> *Facebook apps are created within your Facebook developer account*

Since Facebook changed a lof of its API rules here lies the problem. You cannot just access a post by its ID like using `1104054513000418` you also have to prefix the ID of the page/user who created that post. So if your page's ID is `589476469431696` you actually need to create a combined ID out of both like `589476469431696_1104054513000418` -> `"{page_id}_{post_id}"`. I have no idea if this is interchangeable.

So after creating a new app I was able to get this to work.

Another info: as I was looking for a **user access token** all the time - I found it within my facebook app **advanced** settings. But it seems I don't need it any more.